# Trouble introducing a variable timestep

Tags: c++, timer

i'm currently in university doing Computer Games Programming, in the process of creating a physics engine in C++.

I have been asked to introduce a timestep via the GetTickCount() method, despite the inaccuracies, as it is suitable for the current depth that we're going into time stepping

My problem is that now i have introduced timestep based movement, the objects that have been drawing to screen through two different overrides of an update function don't seem to work.

Through adding breakpoints in the code, it looks as if mElapsedTime doesn't seem to get passed any value and i'm stumped.

Sorry if this post is too wordy or some is off topic, i tried to provide as much context as possible and this is my first post, any help is appreciated.

(frameStartTime parameter just takes a tick count before the frame is updated and drawn)

Edit: mElapsed time of type float, for easier multiplication in the updates of the particle class (e.g. pos.x = velocity.x * timeStep) and this is the reason for the cast from an unsigned long to a float, is it still redundant?

```
void Simulation::gameLoopDelay(DWORD frameStartTime)
{
    DWORD presetFrameInterval = 16;
    DWORD frameProcessingTime = GetTickCount() - frameStartTime;

    if (frameProcessingTime < presetFrameInterval)
    {
        Sleep(presetFrameInterval - frameProcessingTime);
    }

    mElapsedTime = (float)frameProcessingTime / 1000.0f;
}
```

Comment: It's a good first question. A couple notes I have are that your `presetFrameInterval` should be a constant and that the cast to `float` in the last line is redundant. Is `mElapsedTime` a `float`? Is there any way you can take the relevant code and condense it into a complete sample with completely relevant code only?

Comment: Kudos for trying to debug the problem yourself. However, with just this code snippet there’s not much we can tell you. There’s nothing obviously wrong here.

Comment: The most immediate thing i see potentially wrong is the assumption that elapsed time after the sleep is accurate to the requested interval passed to Sleep(). It will most assuredly *not be so*. You don' know how long you were out without refetching GetTickCount() after coming out of the sleep. (and props for the question; its **far** better than most first questions, or even non-first questions. You've tried to analyze and help yourself first, which is *huge*).

Comment: Note in real games you generally want to avoid this frame delay stuff. Just start working on the next frame with a fractional time ([but fix your physics timestep](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)!)

Comment: what values does frameProcessingTime usually have?

Comment: FYI:  Neither GetTickCount nor Sleep have the precision necessary to try to time things down to something like 16 ms.  Also, you probably should re-compute frameProcessingTime after the sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not absolutely sure (because you did not provide enough information), but the first problem I see is that you do `mElapsedTime = (float)frameProcessingTime / 1000.0f;` regardless of `Sleep(...)`. In other words, you forgot to take into account sleeping. To do this you would have to re-fetch `GetTickCount()` after calling `Sleep(...)`. But even then, your code gets too boilerplate and error-prone.

Start approaching your problem by writing  small, flexible, and reusable classes which do simple tasks:

```
class Stopwatch {
public:
  Stopwatch(): _start(0), _elapsed(0), _running(false) {}

  void
  start() {
    if (_running)
      return;

    _running = true;
    _start   = GetTickCount();
  }

  void
  stop() {
    if (!_running)
      return;

    _elapsed += GetTickCount() - _start;
    _running  = false;
  }

  void
  reset() {
    _running = false;
    _elapsed = 0;
  }

  void
  restart() {
    _running = true;
    _elapsed = 0;
    _start   = GetTickCount();
  }

  bool
  isRunning() const {
    return _running;
  }

  DWORD
  elapsed() const {
    return _running ? _elapsed + (GetTickCount() - _start) : _elapsed);
  }

  bool
  hasExpired(DWORD interval) const {
    return elapsed() > interval;
  }

private:
  DWORD _start;
  DWORD _elapsed;
  bool  _running;
};
```

It is straightforward how to utilize this class for your needs.

Secondly, I don't really get why do you use `Sleep`. The last time I've seen the example of frame delaying - was around 5 years ago in some crappy tutorials on writing toy games. This stuff was really popular in old games, but in modern games it does not make sense. Of course if this is the requirement for your assignment, then I apologize, but the remark still applies.

Finally, I'd like to give you additional advice from my own experience with real-time visualization. **Never** write time-dependent code with such raw facilities as `GetTickCount` or other popular crap among Windows API (or Linux API, does not matter) programmers, as it once again smells like out-dated tutorials on creating toy games.

What to use then, you ask? Well, these days we are lucky because there are well-designed, reliable, cross-platform libraries out there such as [Boost](http://www.boost.org/). You should probably be familiar with it, however if you are not - you should definitely do. For your particular problem, there is a module [Boost.Chrono](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/chrono.html) which was carefully designed to work with time properly. I have used it in several projects involving real-time rendering, and I have to admit that it is very robust and worth learning.

Another, library - [Boost.Units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_units.html) - that is a **must** for writing stable and accurate physics engine. This library provides type-safe support for units (force, mass, velocity, acceleration, etc.) and quantities for various unit system models (SI or CGS, for example). It is based on template-metaprogramming, and therefore results in no run-time overhead.

Once again, I understand that your assignment probably does not allow stuff like that. However, I believe that all that I've mentioned here would be valuable to you in the future. By the way, it is a good example of how much more you should know than university assignments offer to be able to solve real life problems.

If you still want more help on your problem in particular - I need more information. For instance, begin with showing us the whole code of your game loop.

Comment: Thanks man, much appreciated. I understand the concept of abstracting away timers and things such as this, and i also do this in my own programming (assignments and the like), but for this specific tutorial implementation i had been told to implement it in this way, i would love to show you more of the project, but i think posting the whole loop would be posting more code than i think might be appropriate for a site like this? I'm not sure. Thanks for the tip about the Boost library, i have heard about it before but not actually checked it out yet, but i think i definitely will now.

Comment: You, might post only those parts of game loop which deal with time **only**, i.e. ones which involve `frameStartTime`, for example. Here, on StackOverflow, of course people will not hug you, if you post the whole ~200 line function body.  You should be able to extract maximum relevant information from your code and post a simplified example, but at the same time it should perfectly reflect your problem. The skill to shrink your code for presentation purposes is useful not only for asking questions here, but for real-life production as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think, basically, you need to change your code to this:

```
void Simulation::gameLoopDelay(DWORD frameStartTime)
{
    DWORD presetFrameInterval = 16;
    DWORD frameProcessingTime = GetTickCount() - frameStartTime;

    if (frameProcessingTime < presetFrameInterval)
    {
        Sleep(presetFrameInterval - frameProcessingTime);
    }

    frameProcessingTime = GetTickCount() - frameStartTime;

    mElapsedTime = (float)frameProcessingTime / 1000.0f;
}
```

This is not the most advised way to do this since `Sleep` here is probably locking out the whole thread. It's probably better to just do the frame at a fractional time, but I think this will fix your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i put this in after reading both answers given and re-fetching the tick count worked, thank you very much and i think i will possibly look at fractional time for my assignment, although for the tutorials i think i am constrained to Sleep().